Failed to mount API Filesystems, on cloned drive, native and vbox
On an identical linux drive, where the only differences are partition UUID's and referencing files, using Fedora 38 64-bit and a UEFI boot, startup only continues to a point citing "Failed to Mount API Filesystems". This seems like a familiar error, and a search isn't providing much insight.
Obviously the updated configuration files etc are allowing grub to find the OS and begin booting and starting system services and run them etc.  Kind of curious what the API filesystems are. Fedora forum argument I remember that turned up in a google search wasn't really shedding light and may have been a different scenario entirely.  All files are verified to be identical and permissions etc set via rsync comparison, drive was cloned via a
tar cf - * | tar xf - 

command and all UUID's on the GPT partition table have been updated and references on the /boot and /boot/efi and /etc directories.
Any ideas ?
Please see screenshot

